Vite / Browserslist: transpile code to be compatible with browsers
I want to use the browserslist rules so I can cover most of the users browsers.
I am using vite and I tried to use @vite/plugin-legacy (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitejs/plugin-legacy) to make the transpilation/polyfills to make my bundle compatible with older browsers.
Here is my config:
# vite.config.ts
    legacy({
      targets: ['cover 99.5%'],
      modernPolyfills: true,
      polyfills: true,
    }),

But when I ctrl+f the build code it still show me reference of many features that is incompatible for older browsers.
E.g last time my team deployed safari 15 crashed because we used regex lookahead..
What I'm missing ?
Am I dreaming and vite is not able to transpile my code like that so easily ?

"What I'm missing?" - You're trying to support a browser that Microsoft stopped supporting almost a decade ago. IE8 doesn't even appear on MDN compatibility lists anymore. So why put yourself through that bother?

I mean I said IE8 but it could be safari 15 for example. Last time we add issues because we used lookahead regex and safari 15 doesnt support it...

I will edit my post
